# Como realizar un Method Post Ajax en Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

En Laravel, mientras trato de enviar una petición via **POST** mediante `ajax`, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> 405 (Method Not Allowed).

```
$("#Enviar").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombre = $('#name').val();
    var nombre = $('#display_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "store",
        data: {
            nombre: nombre
        }, success: function (msg) {
                alert("Se ha realizado el POST con exito "+msg);
        }
    });
});

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
    Route::resource('empresas', 'EmpresaController');
    Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuarioController'); 
    Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController'); 
    Route::resource('sucursales', 'SucursalController');

    Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

});
```

Comment: agrega tu código de otra manera no hay mucho que se pueda hacer

Comment: Las rutas estan por resource. Las separe, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: agrega todas tus rutas, en cual verbo falla: delete, post, put, get?

Comment: Falla en el post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se realiza una petición `ajax` en `laravel` se debe de tener en cuenta algunos aspectos muy importantes como:

1. Cuando la peticion es **post:** Siempre se debe de enviar la variable `_token` con el dato `csrf_token()` que genera laravel por usuario logueado, en caso de que la peticion es **get** "no es obligatorio si recomendable".
2. La `url` debe de estar bien escrita, escribir en etiquetas blade es lo mejor por ejemplo:`{{url("/empresas")}}` o `{{route("empresa.store")}}`, esto en caso de que el `script` este en un archivo **.blade.php**, en caso de que el `script` este en un archivo **.js** se debe de buscar soluciones como crear una variable global **ej:** `var url_global="{{url('/')}}";` y utilizar esta variable en sus `url`'s ajax, **Ej:** `url:url_global+"/empresa"`.

---

Aplicando lo que explique, podria funcionarte lo siguiente:

```
$("#Enviar").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombre = $('#name').val();
    var nombre = $('#display_name').val();
    var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';// ó $("#token").val() si lo tienes en una etiqueta html.
    var data={nombre:nombre,_token:token};
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{route('empresa.store')}}",// ó {{url(/admin/empresa)}} depende a tu peticion se dirigira a el index(get) o tu store(post) de tu controlador 
        data: data,
        success: function (msg) {
                alert("Se ha realizado el POST con exito "+msg);
        }
    });
});


Route::resource('empresas', 'EmpresaController');
```

Ten en cuanta que cuando tu realizas un `group` dentro tus `routes` y le colocas un **prefix**, tu url se alarga, en tu caso seran como estos:

```
_____________________________________________________________________
                Url                         | Method  | Route  
_____________________________________________________________________
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa                  | get     |empresa.index
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa                  | post    |empresa.store
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa/create           | get     |empresa.create
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa/{empresa}        | get     |empresa.show
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa/{empresa}        | put     |empresa.update
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa/{empresa}        | delete  |empresa.destroy
tupagina.dev/admin/empresa/{empresa}/edit   | get     |empresa.edit
```