# InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined."); con laravel 5.7

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, laravel

este es el controlador,

```
public function index()
    {
        //$files = File::all();
       //return view('file/create', compact(''));
        $paises = DB::table('clientes')->pluck("nombre","id")->all();
        return view('file/create',compact('paises'));
    }
     public function selectAjax(Request $request)

    {

        if($request->ajax()){

            $usuario = DB::table('clientes')->where('pais',$request->pais)->pluck("nombre","id")->all();
            $data = view('file',compact('usuario'))->render();
            return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
        }
    }
```

y luego este es es el ajax que esta en la vista,

```
<option>--- Select State ---</option>

@if(!empty($usuario))

  @foreach($usuario as $value)

    <option value="{{ $usuario }}">{{ $usuario }}</option>

  @endforeach

@endif
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("select[nombre='pais']").change(function(){

      var id_country = $(this).val();

     // var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();

      $.ajax({

          url: "<?php echo route('file') ?>",

          method: 'POST',

          data: {id_country:pais},

          success: function(data) {

            $("select[nombre='pais'").html('');

            $("select[nombre='pais'").html(data.options);

          }

      });

  });

</script>
```

por que me da ese error,  no utilizo las rutas ni el modal por que hago un ajax.  pero quisiera saber si eso que hice esta mal,  o se puede hacer de otra manera.

Comment: y tus rutas?? deberias de mostrarlas.

Comment: Hola Ricardo! ¿Probaste remplazando `<?php echo route('file') ?>` por la ruta `/tuRuta`? Te recomiendo evitar mezclar PHP con Javascript, no es una buena práctica ;)

Comment: @MatiasOlivera, ese es el peor de los consejos que podrias dar cuando se trata de laravel.

Comment: Route::resource('file', 'FileController'); uso esa ruta

Comment: @Shassain Es válido cuando se esta utilizando Blade como sistema de plantillas pero no cuando queres separar el cliente del servidor y se utiliza Javascript vanilla o algún framework moderno.

Comment: Anteriormente he respondido a varias preguntas de este tipo pero el que mas se parace es https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168193/como-realizar-un-method-post-ajax-en-laravel/168207#168207 podrias leerlo para que tengas tu respuesta.

Comment: realice los cambios que note estaban malos en lo que me mandaste gracias ya que aprendi mucho mas,  pero sigue presentando el mismo error InvalidArgumentException(“Route [{$name}] not defined.”);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tu problema es que no tienes definida la ruta `file`.**

Te explico: cuando tu creas un

```
Route::resource('file', 'FileController');
```

No solo creas una ruta, sino 7 rutas, todas sirven para realizar el `crud` de cada modelo, tus rutas serian las siguientes:

```
      Url          | Method  | Route  
_____________________________________________________________________
file               | get     |file.index
file               | post    |file.store
file/create        | get     |file.create
file/{file}        | get     |file.show
file/{file}        | put     |file.update
file/{file}        | delete  |file.destroy
file/{file}/edit   | get     |file.edit
```

Lo puedes verificar ejecutando `php artisan route:list` en consola en la dirección de tu proyecto.

Entonces la columna `Route` es la que indica los nombres de rutas y si te das cuenta no existe ninguna que se llame solamente `file`.

En tu caso, al parecer requieres llegar a la función de tu controlador `selectAjax` para lo cual te recomiendo crees otra ruta:

```
Route::post("selectAjax","FileController@selectAjax")->name("file.selectAjax");
```

Dicha ruta nos redirige a la función que deseas. Pero explico un poco esa linea codigo:
`selectAjax` llegaria a ser la **URL** no la ruta, `FileController` llega a ser el controlador donde se procesaran los datos, `selectAjax` es el nombre de la funcion dentro de tu controlador FileController y por ultimo recién se tiene la ruta que llegaria a ser: `file.selectAjax`.

Entonces en el caso de tu `ajax` la linea `url: "<?php echo route('file') ?>",` es la parte que esta fallando, si utilizamos cualquier ruta del `resource` tu deberias de colocar algo como:

```
route('file.index')
route('file.store')
route('file.create')
route('file.show')
route('file.update')
route('file.destroy')
route('file.edit')
```

que son las rutas que tienes. Y si deseas utilizar la ruta post->selectAjax:

```
route("file.selectAjax").
```

En caso de que deseas ingresar por la url puedes utilizar el facade `url()`:

```
url('file')// si el metodo es get se va al index y si es post al store
url('file/create')//redirige a la funcion create
url('file/3')//siendo 3 el id del file este metodo accede a las funciones show cuando el metodo es get,update cuando el metodo es put ó destroy cuando el metodo es delete.
url('file/3/edit')//siendo 3 el id del file este metodo accede a la funcion edit
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias,  me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque no estás mandando el input method. Si agregas en tubdata un campo con el nombre method y algún método predefinido en tu ruta que definiste con el método resourse te debe de funcionar. Actualmente tu ruta necesita un parámetro que no le estás enviando. Como te comentaron no deberías mezclar lenguajes de programación bajo ninguna circunstancia.