# Problema con el metodo POST

Tags: javascript, laravel

¡ Buenas tardes !

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de mandar un array por medio de un Script hacia una ruta para lograr usar una función dentro de un controlador pero mi problema es que al momento de correr mi programa me marca el error:

```
> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
>     in RouteCollection.php line 218
>     at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
>     at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
```

y no se como lograr solucionar este detalle, si alguien me puede orientar le estaría demasiado agradecido les comparto mi Script la ruta y el Controlador

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn-solicitar").on('click',function(){

    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');     

            enviar();               

 });



function enviar(){

var articulos   = Array();

var cantidades  = Array();

var descripciones  = Array();

var usuario     = $('#nombre-usuarios').val();

var area        = $('#nombre-area').val();

var areas       = $('#nombre-area').text();

var localidad   = $('#nombre-localidades').val();

/*cantidades*/

$(".input-cantidad").each(function(){

    cantidades.push($(this).val());

});

/*articulos*/

$(".input-item").each(function(){

    articulos.push($(this).val());

});

/*descripcion*/

$(".input-descripcion").each(function(){

    descripciones.push($(this).val());

});

$.post('guardar-articulos',{'articulos':articulos,'cantidades':cantidades, 'descripciones':descripciones, 'usuario':usuario, 'localidad':localidad, 'area':area, 'areas':areas},function(data){

    $(".body-list").html("");

    $(".list-items").slideUp("slow");

    $("#btn-solicitar").prop('disabled', false);

});
}
```

Esta es mi ruta

```
Route::post('guardar-articulos', 'PapeleriaController@guardar');
```

Este es el controlador

```
public function guardar(){

  $area_       = Area::all();
  $solicita    = Input::get('usuario');
  $area        = Input::get('area');
  $localidad   = Input::get('localidad');
  $areas       = Input::get('areas');
  $responsable = Area::find($area);

   $solicitud = new Solicitud;

     $solicitud->solicita       = $solicita;
     $solicitud->autoriza       = $responsable->responsable;
     $solicitud->mail_autoriza  = $responsable->correo;
     $solicitud->area           = $area;
     $solicutud->status         ='Pendiente';
     $solicitud->id_localidad   =$localidad;

   $solicitud->save();

   $cantidades    = Input::get('cantidades');
   $articulos     = Input::get('articulos');
   $descripciones = Inpput::get('descripciones');
   $folio         = $solicitud->folio;
   $count         = count($artuculos);

   for($item = 0;$item < $count; $item++){

      $papeleria = new Papeleria;

        $papeleria->articulo     = $articulos[$item];
        $papeleria->cantidad     = $cantidades[$item];
        $papeleria->descripcion  = $descripciones[$item];
        $papeleria->folio        = $folio;
        $papeleria->id_localidad = $localidad; 

      $papeleria->save();

   }

   $usuario    = $solicita;
   $area       = $area;
   $mail       = $responsable->correo;
   $articulos  = Papeleria::where('folio', '=', $folio)->get();
   $pedidos    = Solicitud::all();
   $datos      = array('articulos' => $articulos, 'folio' => $folio, 'usuario' => $usuario, 'areas' => $areas, 'mail' => $mail); 

}
```

---

De esta manera queda es Script pero al momento de mandarlo me manda error en la consola

```
function enviar(){

var articulos   = Array();

var cantidades  = Array();

var descripciones  = Array();

var usuario     = $('#nombre-usuarios').val();

var area        = $('#nombre-areas').val();

var areas       = $('#nombre-areas').text();

var localidad   = $('#nombre-localidades').val();

var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';

/*cantidades*/

$(".input-cantidad").each(function(){

    cantidades.push($(this).val());

});

/*articulos*/

$(".input-item").each(function(){

    articulos.push($(this).val());

});

/*descripcion*/

$(".input-descripcion").each(function(){

    descripciones.push($(this).val());

});

var param = {articulos:articulos,cantidades:cantidades,descripciones:descripciones,usuario:usuario,localidad:localidad,area:area,areas:areas,_token:token};

$.ajax({
        url     :  "{{route('guardar-articulos')}}",
        type    :  'POST',
        dataType:  'json',
        data    :   param,
        success :   function (data) {
            alert('send');
        },
        error   :   function() {
            alert('error');
        }
```

Este es el error que manda en la consola

```
jquery.js:4 POST http://localhost/Pape/%7B%7Broute('guardar-articulos')%7D%7D 404 (Not   Found)
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
enviarPedido @ items.js:147
(anonymous) @ items.js:53
dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3
    });    

}
```

Comment: hay mas de una pregunta similar a la tuya en este foro, te recomiendo revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168193/como-realizar-un-method-post-ajax-en-laravel/168207#168207, tu problema es en `$.post('guardar-articulos..'` y secillisima de solucionar

Comment: Hola Shassain, he intentado lo que me recomendaste pero aun así tengo el problema en mi ruta por que no admite los datos que envío

Comment: @Bahamut4321 agrega actualizaciones a tu pregunta mediante la opción "editar", no agregues esa información como respuesta, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys♦ entendido si debía de haber editado mi pregunta y muchas gracias por ayudarme a hacerlo de la manera correcta, ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Bahamut4321 al contrarió gracias a tí, de esta forma verían la información de tu pregunta en el mismo lugar. Con respecto a tu pregunta lo primero que debes revisar es que la url a la cual envíes la petición en verdad este configurada para recibir petición "POST".

Comment: @Bahamut4321, agrega tus rutas, ahora esta ahi tu error