# Obtener datos para las rutas Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, ajax

soy nuevo en laravel y tengo un problema al cargar una ruta, les explico:
tengo un input donde obtengo los datos, primero hago que mi input haga uso de **jquery ui** junto con ajax para que me este autocompletando las respuesta posibles desde una tabla en una base de datos, hasta ahí todo bien, luego según la respuesta seleccionada por el usuario tengo una ruta donde me recibe un parametro para hacer una busqueda en otra tabla de la base de datos, y mostrarme el resultado, es ahí donde tengo el problema, no se como capturar la variable devuelta de **jquery ui**, les dejo mi código para que me ayuden.

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
  <form method="GET" class="row g-3 needs-validation" action="{{route('buscar.index')}}">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="text-info fs-3">Origen</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba la ciudad de origen" aria-label="origen" id="origen" name="origen">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="buscar">Buscar</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ajax

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#origen').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('municipios.search')}}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {             
              console.log(data);
                response(data);
                
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var municipio = ui.item.id;
        console.log(ui.item.id);
                $('#origen').val(ui.item.id);
                
            }
  })


</script>
```

Ruta Laravel

```
Route::get('municipios/{municipio:id?}',[BuscarController::class,'index'])->name('buscar.index');
```

Por cierto estoy utilizando laravel 9

Comment: Falta el token de validacion... busca  laravel ajax y veras ejemplos de como se envia

Answer (score 0):

```
{{-- añade esto en el head --}}
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

var data = { term: request.term,
            _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')};

{{-- o de forma directa --}}

var data = { term: request.term, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' };

 $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('municipios.search')}}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {             
              console.log(data);
                response(data);
                
            }
        });
```

Te dejo
[Como realizar un Method Post Ajax en Laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168193/como-realizar-un-method-post-ajax-en-laravel)